# How to convert png screenshot into CSV file in real time?

Tags: python, csv, artificial-intelligence, real-time, file-conversion

I am making an neural web AI, that will take the pixel information of the game and will decide what buttons to press. It is a fighting game, so I require the data to be given in real time.

In my code I take a screen shot of the game, this part is fast, then I convert it into a CSV file which takes about half a second. Any Idea on how to speed it up? Or do you know of a way where I wont need to use a CSV file to give train/input data to the AI?

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import csv
import numpy as np
import glob
import pandas as pd
import pygetwindow
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image
import threading
import os
import PIL
import glob
import keyboard
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy

number = 0
path = r'C:\Users\samko\Desktop\AI - super figters deluxe\\'
windwonName = 'Superfighters Deluxe v.1.3.7c'



def csvWriter(fil_name, nparray, number): # this bit converts the screenshot into a csv file and writes it into a folder
  example = nparray.tolist()
  with open(fil_name+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(example)
    print('Done: '+str(number))
    number += 1
    return number

with mss.mss() as sct:

    while 1<2:
        name = 'temp_data'
        window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Superfighters Deluxe v.1.3.7c')[0] # gets the location of the window to specify screenshot location
        window.activate()
        x1, y1 = window.topleft
        x2, y2 = window.bottomright

        monitor = {"top": y1, "left": x1, "width": x2-x1, "height": y2-y1}

        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array

        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        numpy.resize(img, (800, 600)) # scales the image so that all are same size

        number = csvWriter(r"C:\Users\samko\Desktop\AI - super figters deluxe\\"+name, img, number)
```

Comment: This won't work like that. You're expecting your AI to make decisions based on pixel values; the possible number of whose is far too big. 800x600 gives you 480,000 input values. Good luck training any NN on that.

Comment: I will be using the Sequential model, where you give smaller portions of the data to smaller neural networks first, then you pass it on to the big neural network. Should work fine I heard. Do you know how to input the data directly as a png image? Without having to convert it into a long line of pixel data?

Comment: You can just feed in the byte values of the png file, that should have the same effect.